# Can any chemicals corrode or dissolve mithril?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Are there any chemicals known to be able to corrode or dissolve mithril in Lord of the Rings?

Comment: Coca-Cola. Just kidding...

Comment: This question should be followed by "where in the periodic table is mithril?"

Comment: @Marakai I’m guessing it’s an alloy with at least one component in the [island of stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability).

Comment: @anaranjada Seeing as that magical island is somewhere above element 110, that would make mithril heavy instead of light. Of course, if you're right, then why didn't the dwarves power spaceships with it, like they did at Area 51? ;)

Comment: There's no reason to think it was completely inert as no real metal is.

Comment: related http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/110138/is-mithril-the-metal-known-as-aluminum http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3774/what-real-world-substance-most-closely-corresponds-to-mithril

Answer (score 7):

### We don't know

It's never explored in any writings. One thing we know is that it doesn't tarnish:

> Its beauty was like to that of common silver, but the beauty of *mithril* did not tarnish or grow dim.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 4: "A Journey in the Dark"</sup>

Since [tarnish is just a fine layer of corrosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarnish), we can conclude that it at least is not corroded by any chemical present in the air. Beyond that, we just don't know.

Comment: So you’re saying that it’s possible that Coca-Cola dissolves mithril. Yup.